# Vaadin navigation through views or UI?

Tags: vaadin

I'm new in Vaadin. I did vaadin example http://demo.vaadin.com/addressbook/. My question is how I can also create another views and menu which will navigate user. Can I do it with MenuBar? Please explain me right way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

I think everything you need is Navigator.

You can instantiate a navigator and attach it to your current page. 
Then you attach views to it, with names.

And when you want to change view, you can simply call `Page.getCurrent().getNavigator.navigate(String viewName)`

[See documentation](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/advanced.navigator.html) for more informations.